# Swift: Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer'

Tags: swift, unsafemutablepointer

I have a little Problem with my Code after updating to Swift 3. I had this Code before the conversion:

```
extension NSData {
  func castToCPointer<T>() -> T {
    let mem = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.alloc(sizeof(T.Type))
    self.getBytes(mem, length: sizeof(T.Type))
    return mem.move()
  }
}
```

And I converted it to this Code and in the 3rd line I get an Error

> ... Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer'

```
extension Data {
  func castToCPointer<T>() -> T{
    let mem = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.allocate(capacity: MemoryLayout<T.Type>.size)
    self.copyBytes(to: mem, count: MemoryLayout<T.Type>.size)
    //self.copyBytes(to: mem, count: MemoryLayout<T.Type>.size)
    return mem.move()
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`copyBytes` expects a `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` as argument:

```
extension Data {
    func castToCPointer<T>() -> T {
        let mem = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.allocate(capacity: 1)
        _ = self.copyBytes(to: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: mem, count: 1))
        return mem.move()
    }
}
```

(`allocate()` takes the number of "items" as argument, not the number of
bytes.)

But note that your method leaks memory, the allocated memory
is deinitialized (with `move()`) but also has to be
deallocated:

```
extension Data {
    func castToCPointer<T>() -> T {
        let mem = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.allocate(capacity: 1)
        _ = self.copyBytes(to: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: mem, count: 1))
        let val =  mem.move()
        mem.deallocate()
        return val
    }
}
```

Comment: Xcode 14 compiler produces this warning which I don't know how to apply:  'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead

Comment: @NateLockwood: I have updated the first method for the current Swift and removed the second method. While it would have been possible to update the second method for Swift 5 as well that one always had the disadvantage to work only with properly aligned memory (which is impossible to guarantee).

Answer (score -1):

You can also use below syntax in extension

```
extension Data {
    func castToCPointer<T>() -> T {
        var bytes = self.bytes
        var val = withUnsafePointer(to: &bytes) { (temp) in
            return unsafeBitCast(temp, to: T.self)
        }
        return val
    }
}
```

---

```
var data:NSData/NSMutableData
var bytes = data.bytes
var val = withUnsafePointer(to: &bytes) { (temp) in
   return unsafeBitCast(temp, to: T.self)
}
```